# How to use if else and recursive functions in this case?

Tags: c

I have been stuck in this exercise for 3 days now. The exercise consists of a "kitchen remodeling" where two colored tiles (blue and yellow) are used.

I start at a corner of the wall and put a blue tile there; around it I put yellow tiles; then around the yellow ones, again a row of blue ones; and so on until the wall is covered.

*Note: I can't use `for`, only `if else`.*

The program must have to output the amount of tiles to buy and all the tiles have 1 on all sides. I tried to create a blue and a yellow function using as input the dimension of the walls and try to find out how much of each one is needed but the result is wrong. Can anyone help me out?

The representation of how the tiles should be positioned:

[image]

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double sum_arithmetic(double x0, double r, int n) {
  return n == 0 ? 0 : x0 + sum_arithmetic(x0 + r, r, n - 1);
}

int blue(int h, int c) {
  int result;
  if ((h % 2) == 1)
    result = sum_arithmetic(1, 4, ((h + 1) / 2)) +
    (c - h) / 2 * h;
  else
    result = sum_arithmetic(1, 4, ((h + 1) / 2)) +
    (c - h + 1) / 2 * h;
  return result;
}

int yellow(int h, int c) {
  return h * c - blue(h, c);
}

//h altura
//c comprimento
void test_two(void) {
  int h;
  int c;
  while (scanf("%d%d", & h, & c) != EOF) {
    int z = blue(h, c);
    int w = yellow(h, c);
    printf("%d %d\n", z, w);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  test_two();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: `while(scanf("%d%d", &h, &c) != EOF)` should be `while(scanf("%d%d", &h, &c) == 2)`

Comment: Are you required to use recursion for this?  There is a pretty simple closed-form solution for a square floor, and it can be extended to rectangular floors without much more trouble.  No looping is involved.

Comment: FYI, `sum_arithmetic(a,b,c)` is `a*c + c*(c-1)*b/2`.

Answer (score 0):

The key to recursion is to repeat same operation on each level to reach the desired outcome. So you need to find the subproblems and generalize them into distinct cases.

Step 1: Split the problem into similar sub problems

Lets take the image you provided and split it into simpler sub problems
[image]

Each layer consists of a horisontal part, vertical part and a corner piece.

[image]

We have 2 base case here.

Case 1: Blue corner

Case 2: Yellow corner

Step 2: Solve the sub problems for all the cases

Count the blues and yellows in both case 1 and case 2. Should be a simple case of maths. Id reccomentd thnking about counting all the squares in odd positions and all squares in even positions.

Step 3: Figure out the recursion step and termination condition

How do you change the input data when you go to the next level of recursion?
At what condition you stop recursing and just return constant value?

Now you should have everything you need to write your code. If done properly you have a easy solution to count blues and yellows.

HINT:

count all blues = start from case 1 function

count all yellows = start from case 2 function

If i give you any more, i would be writing the code for you. I already gave you way too much i think.